# GIT : how to remove untracked files "\\"

Tags: git

For some reason an unusual untracked file exists on all local branches with the following message after i run `git status`

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "\\"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

as i said its on all existing/new local branches how can i remove this ? and what does it actually means ?

Comment: does `git clean -fd` works ?

Comment: Does the file exist when you run `ls -la`?

Comment: *"untracked file exists on all local branches"* -- untracked files are, as their name says, **untracked**. They are not on any branch. A branch is a pointer to a commit, i.e. to a **tracked** state of your project.

Comment: @nbari i ran that without looking on what to be deleted >.< now the project is missing tons of ignored files, lol.

Comment: @axiac true i just mentioned that for the sake of the question ^^

Comment: A simple `rm '\\'` should be enough.

Comment: after running clean and totally destroying the project its not needed anymore ROFL

Comment: still the question how did '\\' ended up here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).

Run `git clean -n` to check what will be deleted, and when you are happy you can remove them with `git clean -fd`.

Comment: this is the correct answer, if anyone got this : PLEASE CONSIDER RUNNING git clean -n first